# Mathematical functions to distinguish Positive and negative integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is going to be a pretty open and loosely defined problem (sincere apologies beforehand).

Are there mathematical functions/equations (over integers) such that:

Given an N (weather its positive or negative is simply unknown) such that when the function is calculated using it, there is a black box way to verify if the original N was positive or negative (using some additional black box functions if necessary).

Essentially, a function that would be computable on N, and the result's magnitude could be used again to infer the sign of the original N (using some other black box operations on it).

The operations permitted are the basic 4 operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication and division).

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you are looking for. I mean, if you have access to the output of the function then $f(n) = n$ seems to have the property that you want. You just look at the output and determine whether it is positive or negative. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "black box method".

Comment: Of course, but even in the result the signs are not visible. So, essentially we are looking for a function that has to behave asymmetrically on magnitude of the result (i am aware it sounds totally absurd, but I risk asking nonetheless)

Comment: Maybe it would help if you could provide an example of exactly what you have access to from the output, what situation this problem arises in, etc. As it is, I can't understand exactly what we are allowed to use because it seems like you don't have access to the actual output of the function if you don't know its sign. If we can't check that it is less than or greater than zero then I presume we also can't check if it is less than or greater than, say, $1$ so it would seem that we have no information about its magnitude either. What exactly do we know about the output?

Comment: Or is it that you only have access to the magnitude of the input and output?

Comment: This question is essentially what i was thinking about (so there is no concrete context and the vagueness) but to clarify I can give an example: The sum of first N integers is given by $(N*(N+1)/2)$. Assuming N=10, the result is 55, but if N=-10, the result is 45. Thus, the magnitude differs depending upon the sign. But, that simply does not tell us anything about the sign of N. I was curious, if we could device a single or set of functions that would give a result with a predictable property that can be tested. So, operations permitted as you said won't allow 'less/greater than' testing.

Comment: But we can do an exact comparison i.e. 'equal to'.

Comment: The function $f(n) = |n| - n$ gives $0$ for $n \geq 0$ and gives an output greater than zero for $n < 0$. But it uses $|\cdot|$. You can replace $|n|$ with $\sqrt{n^2}$ if you are allowed to use square roots. This might be more in the spirit of what you are looking for. Or you can change to $f(n) = |n| + n$ so that the output is $0$ for $n \leq 0$.

Comment: I cannot figure out what is being asked here.